# Using Django ManyToMany symmetrical property to build transitive dependency

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

Is it possible to use the `symmetrical` property from `models.ManyToManyField` so that I can create a transitive dependency between the records?

For example, in my code I have:

```
class User(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Website')
    related_users = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='users', symmetrical=True)
```

When I do:

```
user_a.related_users.add(user_b)
user_a.related_users.all() # returns the user B
user_b.related_users.all() # returns the user A
```

Everything is working as expected here, the relationship is symmetrical.

But when I do:

```
user_b.related_users.add(user_c)
user_b.related_users.all() # returns user A and user C
user_c.related_users.all() # returns user B
```

I want user C to return user A and user B automatically, because user C is user B, which is user A, therefore user C is user A too.

Is it possible to achieve that or do I have to manually add the association between user A and user C?

Comment: Well that is *transitivity*, but that is rather hard. Some databases provide tools to calculate the transitive closure. But it might be better to do it manually by defining a transitive closure many-to-many relation.

Comment: thank you for the input, I didn't know it was named that way, I've updated the question and it will sure help me find the best solution for this case

Answer (score 0):

One simple-ish solution would be to write a custom manager, something along the lines of the following might do the trick if you're only looking to go one level deep

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def two_level_related(self):
        all_related = self.related_users.all()
        for related_user in self.related_users.all():
            all_related.union(related_user.related_users.all())
        return all_related
```